# Replacement of strings within 2 strings in regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a string:

```
dkj   a  *  &     &*(&(*(
//#HELLO
^%@&UJNWDUK()C*(v 8*J DK*9
//#HE#$^&&(akls#$98akdjl ak#@sjdkja
//
%^&*(//#HELLO//#BYE<><>
//#BYE
^%@&UJNWDUK()C*(v 8*J DK*90K )
//#HELLO
&*^J$XUK  8j8 j jk kk8(&*(
//#BYE
```

and I need to have 2 groups such as each group must start with //HELLO then there should be a next line and any type of text can follow (.*) but it will end with a //BYE preceded by a line:

```
1)
//#HELLO
^%@&UJNWDUK()C*(v 8*J DK*9
//#HE#$^&&(akls#$98akdjl ak#@sjdkja
//
%^&*(//#HELLO//#BYE<><>
//#BYE

2)
//#HELLO
&*^J$XUK  8j8 j jk kk8(&*(
//#BYE
```

and replaces the original string to this: (basically adding // to each line of each group)

```
dkj   a  *  &     &*(&(*(
////#HELLO
//^%@&UJNWDUK()C*(v 8*J DK*9
////#HE#$^&&(akls#$98akdjl ak#@sjdkja
////
//%^&*(//#HELLO//#BYE<><>
////#BYE
^%@&UJNWDUK()C*(v 8*J DK*90K )
////#HELLO
//&*^J$XUK  8j8 j jk kk8(&*(
////#BYE
```

Here is my current progress:
I have

```
\/\/#HELLO\n.*?\/\/#BYE[\n$]
```

However im not sure how to go about the replacement, I'm thinking separating each line per group using \G after the //#HELLO and ending with //#BYE

Comment: for starters you didn't really ASK a question. Im going to assume you need help with the regex. But this isn't a "do my work for free site" so could you post your current progress and mention what you need help with? Could you specifically state your questions?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that

Comment: I hope the grouping into separate lines will at least help you getting started.

Comment: NEVERMIND, Everyone I decided to move with an iterational approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complex, but this will do it:

Search: `(?m)(//#HELLO[\r\n]+|\G(?://#BYE|(?=(?:[^#]|#(?!HELLO[\r\n]+))*#BYE)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*))`

Replace: `//$1`

In Groovy:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(/(?m)(\/\/#HELLO[\r\n]+|\G(?:\/\/#BYE|(?=(?:[^#]|#(?!HELLO[\r\n]+))*#BYE)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*))/, '//$1');
```

Comment: Hey Luis, a bit similar to your question from yesterday, but not the same... Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: It does, but I am added a comment that I am using an iterative approach because I need to do more manipulation to the replacements

Answer (score 1):

For grouping into separate lines use the following regex:

```
//#HELLO\r(.*[\n\r]+)*//#BYE\r?
```

- `\r` - Newline character
- `[\n\r]` - Enter characters
- `*?` - Non-greedy match
- `?`- Match 1 or 0 times

You can take out the `?` at the end if it *always* ends with a newline.

You can then use the group (The value inside the brackets) to search and replace.

Comment: You probably want something like `\r\n?|\n` for newlines.